# How to center only one element in a row of 2 elements in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my layout I have two Widgets in a row, one text and the an icon.

As shown below, assume that * refers to the icon, and using "-" to represent the row:

```
----------------------------
           Text          *  
----------------------------
```

How do I make my text centered in the entire row, and the icon to the right end ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The main thing you need to notice is that if you don't want to use `Stack` you should provide same width-consuming widgets both on left and right.

I would do this with either `Expanded` and `Padding`

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 32.0),
        child: Text(
          "Text",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Icon(Icons.add, size: 32.0,)
  ],
)
```

or with `Row`'s `mainAxisAlignment` and a `SizedBox`

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    const SizedBox(width: 32.0),
    Text("Text"),
    Icon(Icons.add, size: 32.0)
  ],
)
```

or with `Expanded` and a `SizedBox` on the left instead of the padding :).  The padding or extra container on the left is so that the textAlign will truly center the text in the row taking into account the space taken up by the Icon.

Comment: why exactly 32?

Comment: @reverie_ss to "counter" the icon - icon's size is 32, so the Container must be the same width on the other size. Without it, the text would appear (slightly) off-center.

Answer (score 36):

Simply use `Expanded` and `Spacer` widgets on left/right side and put your widget inside the `Expanded`:

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    Spacer(),
    Text('Text'),
    Expanded(
      child: Text('*'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Result:
[image: Flutter center by one element in Row]

Comment: Very nice.  I still have trouble wrapping my head around this though. Can you explain more why it works ?

Comment: @log0 `Text` widget is placed between `Spacer` and `Expanded`, which equally share the rest of the available width

Answer (score 23):

[image]

**1. Using `Row`** (not very flexible though)

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(child: Center(child: Text('Center'))),
    Text("#"),
  ],
)
```

---

**2. Using `Stack`** (flexible)

```dart
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Align(child: Text('Center')),
      Positioned(right: 0, child: Text('#')),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: This places "Center" a little to the left of center.

Comment: @Swift Replace `Row` with `Stack`, remove `Expanded` and wrap `Text` in `Positioned(right: 0, child: Text("*")`

Answer (score 18):

I found it necessary to use a `Stack` to get Text to be truly centered:

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text('Text'),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: Text('*'),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: This worked the best for me, and only this really centered correctly. Thanks

Comment: Only issue is that the first `Align` does not take the second in consideration in a stack (as opposed to say a `Row`). Hence the 2 widgets could overlap...

Answer (score 6):

For flexibility reasons I recommend to use Expanded widgets:

```
       Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container()),
              Expanded(
                flex: 8,
                child: Text('Your Text',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(flex: 1, child: IconButton(...))
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I solved my centering problem by adjusting the `flex` property of the `Spacer` widget -

```
Row(children: [
        Spacer(flex: 3),//3 was for my case, It might be changed for your widgets
        Text('Center'),
        Spacer(flex: 1),//1 was also for my case, It might be changed on for your widgets
        Text("*")]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a Stack with two children one as its own Row with an expansion to push elements to the walls and one as a Center item that has your desired center Widget. For example:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        leftWidgetHere,
        Expanded(
          child: Container(),
        ),
        rightWidgetHere,
      ],
    ),
    Center(
      child: centerWidgetHere,
    ),
  ],
);
```

As a useful component class:

```
class CenteredRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const CenteredRow({Key? key, required this.left, required this.center, required this.right}) : super(key: key);
  final Widget left;
  final Widget center;
  final Widget right;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            left,
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
            right,
          ],
        ),
        Center(
          child: center,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another icon in the start and set the opacity to zero.

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
   children: [
      CloseButton(
         onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      ),
      Text('text',),

      Opacity(
         opacity: 0,
         child: Icon(Icons.close),
         ),
       ],
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: I]

I wanted this here , there are **3 items in one `Row` the first and second one is at top of that `Row` while the last `Icon` was at the center of that row vertically**.
My approach was use of `IntrinsicHeight` widget provider by flutter

*Note : No any static height given in this solution*

```
                IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.offline_bolt_sharp,
                          color: AppColors.secondary,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hSpacing(times: .5),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                text: '',
                                style: TextStyle(),
                                children: <TextSpan>[
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text: "Free Delivery ",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        color: AppColors.secondary,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                        ..onTap = () {}),
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Tomorrow 5 Aug",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      color: AppColors.secondary,
                                    ),
                                    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                      ..onTap = () {},
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            vSpacing(times: .5),
                            Text(
                              "On minimum spend of Rs ${commaNumber(3000)}",
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.secondary,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                            size: 20,
                            color: AppColors.secondary,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
```

This way you stretch all the element of `Row` to equal height then position by `alignment` property according to your need.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me without Stack. But it is the other way around. "Text" goes to left "*" goes to center:

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text("text",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption),
        ),
        Text("*"),
        Spacer(),
      ],
    )
```