# Here i want the back button icon in the start and the text in the center of the row in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        title: 'testing row',
        home: TestingRow(),
      ),
    );

class TestingRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestingRow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const [
          Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
            size: 20.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              'PERSONAL INFORMATION',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to use [AppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) widget

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
class TestingRow extends StatelessWidget {
const TestingRow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    
    children: const [
      Icon(
        Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
        size: 20.0,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'PERSONAL INFORMATION',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class TestingRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestingRow({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const [
          Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
            size: 20.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Expanded( //Added expanded so it takes remaining space and center itself
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'PERSONAL INFORMATION',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, and the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587003/how-to-center-only-one-element-in-a-row-of-2-elements-in-flutter)
if the row of yours is just the icon and the text
adding an empty contianer and making

```
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```

will do the trick

Code:

```
 Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children:  [
            const Icon(
              Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            const Text(
                'PERSONAL INFORMATION',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                ),
              ),

            Container(width: 20,),
          ],
        ),
```